# C# - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

I am working on a simple windows forms application that the user enters a string with delimiters and I parse the string and only get the variables out of the string.
So for example if the user enters:

```
2X + 5Y + z^3
```

I extract the values 2,5 and 3 from the "equation" and simply add them together.

This is how I get the integer values from a string.

```
int thirdValue
string temp;
temp = Regex.Match(variables[3], @"\d+").Value
thirdValue = int.Parse(temp);
```

`variables` is just an array of strings I use to store strings after parsing.

However, I get the following error when I run the application:

> Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: Print out the values inside `temp` please. That might enlighten you somewhat.

Comment: This won't even compile - can you show your real code?  (Match.Value is a `string`, so you can't assign to `int temp`, etc)

Comment: Exactly how can you assign regex match to int?

Comment: I am sorry, it was typo, temp is a string.

Comment: @user2301717 We also need to know what's stored in `variables[3]`

Comment: I mentioned in my question. "variables" is just an array of strings, that i use to store string values after parsing.

Answer (score 4):

Why i everyone moaning about this question and marking it down? it's incredibly easy to explain what is happening and the questioner was right to say it as he did. There is nothing wrong whatsoever.

```
Regex.Match(variables[3], @"\d+").Value
```

throws a `Input string was not in a correct format..` *FormatException* if the string (here it's `variables[3]`) doesn't contain any numbers. **It also does it if it can't *access* `variables[3]` within the memory stack of an Array when running as a service. I SUSPECT THIS IS A BUG** The error is that the `.Value` is empty and the `.Match` failed.

Now quite honestly this is a feature masquerading as a bug if you ask me, but it's meant to be a design feature. The right way (IMHO) to have done this method would be to return a blank string. But they don't they throw a *FormatException*. Go figure. It is for this reason you were advised by `astef` to not even bother with Regex because it throws exceptions and is confusing. But he got marked down too!

The way round it is to use this simple additional method they also made

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(variables[3], @"\d+")){
   temp = Regex.Match(variables[3], @"\d+").Value
}
```

If this *still* doesn't work for you you cannot use Regex for this. I have seen in a `c# service` that this doesn't work and throws incorrect errors.  So I had to stop using Regex

Comment: I agree.  This is a legit question for people who are new to C# and this answer is highly informative.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer simple and lightweight solutions without `Regex`:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2X + 65Y + z^3".GetNumbersFromString().Sum());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> GetNumbersFromString(this string input)
    {
        StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char ch in input)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(ch))
                number.Append(ch);                
            else if (number.Length > 0)
            {
                yield return int.Parse(number.ToString());
                number.Clear();
            }
        }
        yield return int.Parse(number.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the string to char array and check if its a digit and count them up.

```
        string temp = textBox1.Text;
        char[] arra = temp.ToCharArray();
        int total = 0;
        foreach (char t in arra)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(t))
            {
                total += int.Parse(t + "");
            }
        }
        textBox1.Text = total.ToString();
```

Comment: Buggy in the case of number bigger than 9: "2X + 65Y + z^3"

Comment: Though we need better explanation of the task to be sure

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
string temp;
temp = Regex.Matches(textBox1.Text, @"\d+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[2].Value;
int thirdValue = int.Parse(temp);
```